# Direct X 11 and GPU acceleration (Simulations etc) - where to start?

Tags: gpu, directx-11, hardware-acceleration

I am using SharpDX and am fairly comfortable with it at the moment, but for an assessment for university, I need to create a demo which utilizes some sort of GPU acceleration. This is an 'independent research' task - what that means is, I assigned myself this task. I am legitimately interested in GPU acceleration in games, but right now it feels like I threw myself way too far into the deep.

I am planning to do a particle system (it will be a very BASIC system, with particles firing/falling/dieing) but I need a starting point.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Articles to read? things to consider? I have googled my heart out on things like "GPU acceleration DirectX", but I can't find any solid results! I wish I had a sort of 'hello world' for GPU acceleration..!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to understand how to build a GPU particle system, I suggest you to read the book "[Practical Rendering And Compution with Direct3D11](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1568817207)", where you will find an entire chapter dedicated on how to implement a simple GPU particle system.

Then the most trickiest part is probably the sorting algorithm which is not detailed in the previous book, but you can have a look at ComputeShaderSort11 sample from the old DirectX June 2010 that could help you a lot (the implementation is quite efficient).

Also, I did a full particle engine on the GPU with SharpDX at my work, so It is perfectly achievable with SharpDX.